# Qemu - irq 22 : 'nobody cared (try booting with the “irqpoll” option)'

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, qemu

I have PCIdevice in Qemu.

Inside VM (ubuntu image, kernel 4.15), I have written a PCI Driver over that device. 
I used **request_irq** to attach the IRQ handler, over irq line 11.

I can see my interrupt name with interrupt pin '11' in /proc/interrupts.

But when I am doing pci_irq_assert in Qemu.

I am getting following error which I can see in dmesg logs.

```
irq 22 : 'nobody cared (try booting with the “irqpoll” option)'
```

Driver Code:

**pci_probe function**

```
/* IRQ setup. */
pci_read_config_byte(dev, PCI_INTERRUPT_LINE, &val);
pci_irq = val;
if (request_irq(pci_irq, irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "pci_irq_handler0", &major) < 0) {
    dev_err(&(dev->dev), "request_irq\n");
    goto error;
}
```

**irq_handler** function:

```
int devi;
irqreturn_t ret;
u32 irq_status;
devi = *(int *)dev;
if (devi == major) {
    irq_status = ioread32(mmio + IO_IRQ_STATUS);
    pr_info("interrupt irq = %d dev = %d irq_status = %llx\n",
            irq, devi, (unsigned long long)irq_status);
    /* Must do this ACK, or else the interrupts just keeps firing. */
    iowrite32(irq_status, mmio + IO_IRQ_ACK);
    ret = IRQ_HANDLED;
} else {
    ret = IRQ_NONE;
}
return ret;`
```

Qemu Device:

```
pci_conf[PCI_INTERRUPT_PIN] = 0x02;

/* this device support interrupt */
d->irq = pci_allocate_irq(pci_dev);
```

Comment: Show us the code!

Comment: I have followed this  link to write the drivercode 
https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/a8e11e6de9092919ff833ed95dad02d173559564/kernel_module/pci.c

Comment: And do you have the device behind the PCI bus? Show your code, show output of `lspci -nk -vv`, show the output of `cat /proc/interrupts` (this one before and after you got a message).

Comment: I have followed this link to make the changes regarding IRQ in Qemu pci device 
http://tic-le-polard.blogspot.com/2015/01/emulate-pci-device-with-qemu.html

Comment: before insmod priver.ko :: cat /proc/interrupts
  0:         31   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  1:        180   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
  7:          0   IO-APIC   7-edge      parport0
  8:          1   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
  9:          0   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
 12:         54   IO-APIC  12-edge      i8042
 16:          0   IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb2
 17:          0   IO-APIC  17-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb3
 18:          0   IO-APIC  18-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb4
 19:        148   IO-APIC  19-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
 22:        165   IO-APIC  22-fasteoi   enp0s2

Comment: after insmod driver.ko : cat /ptoc/interrupts 
11:          0   IO-APIC  11-fasteoi   legacy_irq

I can see my irq here

Comment: Output of lspci::

        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 11

Comment: Output of dmesg:
after enabling legacy intx, device's irq  is [11]
[  150.150764] irq 22: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[  150.150769] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G           OE    4.15.0-33-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[  150.150770] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009), BIOS rel-1.11.0-0-g63451fca13-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/2014

Comment: @RaghavMahajan: Please, add  **your code** into the **question post**. This is what others asked you. See also [ask].